# Angular 9 logout and clear session storage

Tags: angular, window, reload, session-storage

in this logout function, I expect it do a http get method, and then get status code. If the code is correct, it will clear the session storage, and refresh window.
However, mostly, it won't print data.code. Only if I click more times, then, it will work.

in my component:

```
  logout() {
    this.userService.userLogout().subscribe( data => {
        console.log(data.code);
        if ( data.code === 0 ) {
          this.tokenStorageService.signOut();
          window.location.reload();
        }
    });
  }
```

in my UserService do http get method:

```
  userLogin(credentials): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.get<Data>(API_URL + 'login');
  }
```

in my TokenStorageService:

```
  signOut(): void {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }
```

https://github.com/Jin-Teng/waffle/

Thanks

Comment: have you put debugger there inside subscribe ?